# GUI via Fyne: changing elements on app page on button clicking

Tags: go, user-interface, fyne

What is the best practice to change elements on an app page at button clicking.
For example, I have such code

```
package main

import (
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/container"
    "fyne.io/fyne/v2/widget"
)

func main() {
    a := app.New()
    w := a.NewWindow("Hello")

    hello := widget.NewLabel("Hello Fyne!")
    w.SetContent(container.NewVBox(
        hello,
        widget.NewButton("Hi!", func() {
            // do something
        }),
    ))

    w.ShowAndRun()
}
```

I want to change elements on this window if clicking on a NewButton. And display a new Buttons with different functions at their clicking

Comment: Have you studied the official Fyne demo program? Last time I checked, it was rather extensive in the actions implemented in its UI.

Comment: maybe [How to remove objects from golang fyne container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63995289/10197418) is helpful?

Comment: Maybe the “updating content” tutorial could help? https://youtu.be/h2ZOdTA3ew4

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the content of a container you will want to set the Container to a variable so you can access its methods and fields later to manipulate the content.

```
content := container.NewVBox(…)
w.SetContent(container)
```

Then you can use methods on `content` or change its `Objects` field then call `Refresh()`.